# Getting the project root

Tags: php, path

I keep getting confused when trying to include files that will have different paths in a local environment vs production.

For example, I have this in my `usercontroller.php` file:

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/config.php');
```

On my local host, `usercontroller.php` is located in `www/myproject/inc/` and `config.php` is in `www/myproject/` (the project root directory)

This fails.

All I want is a way to define the projects root. i.e on localhost it's `www/projectname` and in productions it's `/` Since files are located inside the `projectname` directory on my localhost, it's causing issues on my production server.

What is the best way to simply define a base path and build my `require_once` from that?

i.e. `require_once($basePath . 'inc/filename.php'`

Answer (score 1):

Most projects use a `config.inc.php` file located in a common place where these things can be defined.

**config.inc.php**

```
define('ROOT_FOLDER', '/');
define('APPLICATION_LINK', 'http://www.example.com/mysite');
```

**script.php**

```
require ('../config.inc.php');
echo '<a href="' . APPLICATION_LINK . '">Go home</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Every project should contain a config.php file that holds this information.

config.php

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'PRODUCTION');
// define('ENVIRONMENT', 'TESTING');
// define('ENVIRONMENT', 'DEVELOPMENT');

switch (ENVIRONMENT) {
    case 'PRODUCTION':
        define('BASE_URL', 'http://www.mysite.com');
        define('BASE_PATH', '/');
        break;
    case 'TESTING':
        define('BASE_URL', 'http://test.mysite.com');
        define('BASE_PATH', '/test/');
        break;
    case 'DEVELOPMENT':
        define('BASE_URL', 'http://localhost/');
        define('BASE_PATH', '/www/myproject/');
        break;
}
```

Then maybe have a URL helper file.

url_helper.php

```
function site_url($relative) {
    return BASE_URL . $relative;
}

function redirect($uri = '', $method = 'location', $http_response_code = 302) {
    if ( ! preg_match('#^https?://#i', $uri)) {
        $uri = site_url($uri);
    }

    switch($method) {
        case 'refresh' : header("Refresh:0;url=".$uri);
                break;
        default : header("Location: ".$uri, TRUE, $http_response_code);
                break;
    }
    exit;
}
```

And a load helper.

load_helper.php

```
function load_file($uri) {
    require BASE_PATH . $uri;
}

function load_class($class) {
    if ( ! class_exists($class))
        load_file('class/' . $class);
}
```

These functions could be more robust to suit your needs. The advantage is you can have different configurations for Production/Development, various servers, or simply for specific environments. If you always use the site_url function to generate URLs around your site, you can easily change how your URLs are interpreted by making one change in a single file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this could do the trick!

```
switch(dirname(__FILE__)) {
case '/www/myproject/inc/':
    //DEFINE SOMETHING
break;
case '/www/myproject/':
    //DEFINE SOMETHING
break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) `__DIR__` returns the directory of the file where it was used.

> **DIR** - The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of the included file is returned. This is equivalent to dirname(**FILE**). This directory name does not have a trailing slash unless it is the root directory. (Added in PHP 5.3.0.)

To include a file in an outer directory you'll have to use `..` to "get out" of the inner directory.

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '../config.php');
```

---

On a side note, I would suggest you check out [FIG's autoloading standards](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) if you are using PHP's namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is late, but you haven't accepted any yet, so I thought I'd throw in to the pot what I use for most of my applications.

First things first, from the file you call your `config.php` from, you will always need to use a relative reference for it, ie `require_once '../config.php';` from your example.   Granted, you can 'gather' the full path to the config file from PHP commands, but *why* would you do that when you know its one directory up, and within it, you can then `define` the base path for the entire project.  For example, in your `www/myproject/inc/usercontroller.php` file, the top would look like:

```
<?php
require_once '../config.php';
```

And then, to auto-get the full basepath of the project for use in other includes or the like, in your config, you'd have something like:

```
<?php
$basepath = dirname(__FILE__);
define('BASEPATH', $basepath);
//Or all in one line:
define('BASEPATH', dirname(__FILE__));
```

From there, just use `BASEPATH` when you need the full path to the root of the project. ^^